# Invalid escape sequence with my Regex

Tags: java, regex

I keep getting invalid escape sequence with my Regex

```
private String mathA = "(\d)[ + ](\d)\\s=\?";
```

I erased every part of the Regex but no matter what I took out it kept giving me the same error. I want to match "5 + 3 =?" where the 5 and 3 can be any digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in your expression and code.

First of all, you have to escape backslashes with another backslash. Additionally, you are using a character class `[...]`, so you if you have `[a   e   aaaa]` this will only match `ae`. So, `[ + ]` will only match a space or a plus.

You can change your code to this:

```
private String mathA = "(\\d) [+] (\\d)\\s=\\?";
// or escaping +
private String mathA = "(\\d) \\+ (\\d)\\s=\\?";
```

Btw, if you want match multiple digits, you can use:

```
private String mathA = "(\\d+) [+] (\\d+)\\s=\\?";
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks that helped, I thought I finally had the hang of regex as well but I guess not.

Comment: @TeenCoder glad to help. I've updated the answer with some explanatory changes

Answer (score 0):

Java treats the character `\\` specially in strings. The character is treated as an escape to allow for representing, e.g., new lines as `\n`. To get a literal backslash in a string, you need to use two back slashes`\\\\`.

The error is occurring because Java sees, for example `\\d` and doesn't know what to do with it.

Also make sure that your `\\\\` becomes `\\\\\\\\` to get around the fact that regex uses the same escape character to get a literal backslash. Four backlashes in the code = 2 in the string = 1 literal backlash in the match.

Also, `?` should not be escaped, you don't want a literal question mark.